# Oracle OLEDB Provider Not Found

Tags: oracle, excel, oledb, vba

I am trying to connect to an Oracle Database on a new machine. I originally had this set up to connect via Microsoft OLE, but that is beyond deprecated, so I installed ODAC on my machine, and tried the followed connection string

```
dim conn as Connection: set conn = new Connection

connString = "Provider=OraOLEDB;" & _
        "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=hostsite.com)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=prod)));" & _
        "User Id=myname;Password=mypassword;"

conn.open connString
```

When I run this, I receive the following error:

`Provider cannot be found. It may not be properly installed`

I ran the OUI and installed the Oracle OLEDB and check the Environment variables and everything seems to be in order.

Although, when I run a test UDL file, I cannot find the Oracle providers anywhere.

My Oracle home directory is c:\Oracle\ORACLE_HOME and both that and the bin are included in my variables.

Comment: Try `Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;`

Comment: Can I please give you a kiss?!?!?!?!?!

Comment: A kiss over a distance of 6500km?